# Rash development during ketogenic diet?

Tags: rash, ketosis

Going through the third week of a ketogenic diet, i've developed tickling feeling on whole my body, a local rash on my hand ankle has also emerged. What might be the underlying cause?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help], again of necessary, since this phrased awfully close to receive a response like:  Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have it looked at, we can't tell you whether your rash is normal or not on this site.  Although the person answering below gave a general response to "can there be rashes during ketosis" that doesn't mean it applies to your individual situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**: This is not a comment on your rash as that would be getting into the realms of medical advice; instead, I'll treat it as a general question.

## Can there be a rash associated with a ketotic state?

**It seems so**. There is a skin condition called *prurigo pigemntosa* (aka Nagashima disease), which has an unclear cause – friction, or contact dermatitis to one or more substances – but has an association with ketotic states. From DermNetNZ:

> Prurigo pigmentosa is a rare inflammatory skin condition of unknown cause. It is characterized by a recurrent itchy rash with netlike hyperpigmentation.
>
> ...
>
> It has been associated in some patients with **ketotic states** associated with diabetes, fasting and post-bariatric surgery

From [*Prurigo pigmentosa*](https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/prurigo-pigmentosa) on DermNetNZ.

The rash has been [reported to clear with resolution of ketosis](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/6rv324m4):

> Another notable association frequently reported in the literature is with ketosis resulting from diabetes, diet, eating disorders, or pregnancy. Although several authors have reported improvement of the eruption upon resolution of ketosis, there is no noted association with blood glucose levels.

From [*Prurigo pigmentosa: Report of two cases in the United States and review of the literature*](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/6rv324m4).

Comment: @DoctorWhom - good edit, thanks! I had intended the initial heading to be the general (non-personal) form of the question posed by OP; your phrasing makes it read much better though! Cheers